I am trying to learn connecting firebase auth with flutter project, during the initial setup I am facing error
project level build.gradle and i am using the latest version of kotlin

the error:
C:/Users/hp/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/648640f83817e7438e3934ba83addfe2/transformed/jetified-play-services-measurement-api-22.0.1-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.gmscore.integ.client.measurement_api_measurement_api.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

┌─ Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                     │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then │
│ update D:\phone_auth\android\build.gradle:                                                 │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                    │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

I fixed the same issue by deleting the folder ,your case this C:/Users/hp/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/648640f83817e7438e3934ba83addfe2
and then Flutter clean after that flutter pub get and run
